# Cannot find referrals section in branch.io dashboard?

Tags: android, branch.io, referrals

I was looking for a Referrals and credits API and found Branch. I create a free account and in the Dashboard I can't see the Referrals sections like in this link [enter link description here](http://Cannot%20find%20referrals%20section%20in%20branch.io%20SDK).
I sent an email but doesn't have an answer back. I want to know if they're still revamping the referral system and if not why is not showing in dashboard, and finally where is the documentation for that part to make it work in android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch.io don't support referral anymore. You need to implement it manually.

Answer (score 1):

A Branchster here:

Our legacy referral-based product is being revamped and there will be an updated version. As of now, we don't have an ETA on this, however, in the meanwhile, you can make use of Branch's deep-linking and have your own referral system around it.

Comment: Did you guys ever add referrals back? I can request a demo of referrals from the branch website but can't find referrals in the dashboard 

Comment: yes that's still the case. you can have your own referral system inhouse using branch links